# Map Custom domain to Azure web app deployment slot

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I want to automate mapping a custom domain for my web app's deployment slots(not the production slot). I have achieved this through the Azure Portal with this [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/Azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-domain#map-your-domain), but I can't get it to work through the AZ CLI. It appears that in the cli, only through for the production slot is possible to achieve mapping a custom domain. This is the command to do it for the production slot but I can not see an option for other slots on the same web app. Also whatever I try on the `webapp-name` parameter to try and reference the slot(as supposingly is a separate web app) doesn't work(it keeps giving me `app not found errors`):

`az webapp config hostname add --webapp-name <app_slot_name> --resource-group <rg> --hostname <cname_that_already_exists>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `--slot`.

## Offical doc.

[az webapp config hostname add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp/config/hostname?view=azure-cli-latest#az_webapp_config_hostname_add-examples)

```
az webapp config hostname add [--hostname]
                          [--ids]
                          [--resource-group]
                          [--slot]
                          [--subscription]
                          [--webapp-name]
```